# lost session after redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

Newly added description: (sorry for not mentioning)

The ApplicationController.current_account is defined as:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  class << self
    def current_account
      @current_account
    end
    def current_account=(value)
      @current_account = value
    end
  end
```

=========

I encountered a strange performance in my current project, which is about session. The strange part is it was normal in Safari but failed in other browsers (includes chrome, firefox and opera).

There is a registration form for input of part of the key information (email, password, etc) and is submitted to an action called "create"

This is the basic code of create action:

```
@account = Account.new(params[:account])
if @account.save
  ApplicationController.current_account = @account
  session[:current_account] = ApplicationController.current_account
  session[:account] = ApplicationController.current_account.id

  email = @account.email
  Mailer.deliver_account_confirmation(email)

  flash[:type] = "success"
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully Created Account"

  redirect_to :controller => "accounts", :action => "create_step_2"
else
  flash[:type] = "error"
  flash[:title] = "Oops, something wasn't right."
  flash[:notice] = "Mistakes are marked below in red. Please fix them and resubmit the form. Thanks."
  render :action => "new"
end
```

Also I created a before_filter in the application controller, which has the following code:

```
ApplicationController.current_account = Account.find_by_id(session[:current_account].id) unless session[:current_account].blank?
```

For Safari, there is no any problem. But for the other browsers, the session[:current_account] does not exist and so produced the following error message:

```
RuntimeError in AccountsController#create_step_2

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

Please could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1] don't write

```
ApplicationController.current_account
```

Just

```
current_account
```

2] in your application_controller

```
   def current_account
     session[:current_account]
   end
```

3]

```
  ApplicationController.current_account = @account
  session[:current_account] = ApplicationController.current_account
  session[:account] = ApplicationController.current_account.id
```

should be

```
  session[:current_account] = @account
  session[:account] = @account.id
```

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to say that current_account is defined as:

    class ApplicationController << ActionController::Base
      class << self
        def current_account
          @current_account
        end
        def current_account=(value)
          @current_account = value
        end
      end
    ...

So could I still use step 1 and 2 stated above?

Comment: sorry then @peter i am not sure then it will work for you.I never used like it before so not an idea bout it. Sorry again

Comment: I used class variable instead of instance variable in the ApplicationController because some validation codes in the account model will need the current_account. (ie. validates_xxx, :if=>:some_method_needed_current_account). I don't know how to pass instance variable to a model's validation.